# No me funciona el HashSet

Tags: java

[image: Ejercicio]

Hola soy nuevo en el mundo de la programacion y necesito resolver este ejercicio para seguir y estoy trabadisimo,  le di mil vueltas y no hay forma de que me salga. no se en donde estoy fallando si alguien me ayuda.. gracias!

```
class ClubDeNoHomeros {     
    List<String> integrantes = Arrays.asList("Homero", "Carl", "Lenny", "Homero", "Homero");
    
    long cantidadIntegrantes() {   
        return integrantes.size();     
    }      
}
```

tengo que modificar integrantes de modo que no queden repetidos.
probe introduciendole lo siguiente y me da error igual.

Set  noHomeros = new HashSet(integrantes);

---

Es lo que me arroja al pasarle el codigo:

```
class ClubDeNoHomeros {
  
  List<String> integrantes = Arrays.asList("Homero", "Carl", "Lenny", "Homero", "Homero");
  
  long cantidadIntegrantes() {
    return integrantes.size();
  }
  
 public Set<String> getNoHomeros() {           
        Set<String> noHomeros = new HashSet<>(integrantes);
        return noHomeros;  
    }          
  
}
```

Comment: Hola. Pon el código como texto, no como imagen y dinos cuál es exactamente el problema o error. Pulsa en [edit] para completar la pregunta.

Comment: Listo, espero puedas ayudarme!

Comment: Y, ¿qué es lo que tiene que hacer tu código exactamente? No lo explicas en la pregunta.

Comment: tengo que modificar integrantes de modo que no queden repetidos. probe introduciendole lo siguiente y me da error igual.

Set noHomeros = new HashSet(integrantes);

Comment: Ya, pero tratándose de una propiedad de una clase, no queda claro qué entiendes por *modificar*. ¿Debes crear un método en el cual, a partir de `integrantes` se cree un Set de valores únicos? ¿Se trata de cambiar `integrantes` por otro tipo de objeto? etc.

Comment: List<String> integrantes = Arrays.asList("Homero", "Carl", "Lenny", "Homero", "Homero");                     Exactamente modifique el codigo a esto y me tira el siguiente error:  ¡Ups! Tu solución no se puede ejecutar
Resultados:
(line 5, column 2): unexpected Period

Comment: sobre lo que me preguntas, se trata de cambiar la lista llamada en este caso integrantes por un HashSet que no contenga repetidos de la lista.

Answer (score 1):

Simplemente puedes crear un `HashSet` y agregar la lista. Él sólo se encargará de eliminar los duplicados. Tu código estaba casi correcto, sólo que estabas omitiendo `<>` al crear el `Set`.

Yo lo he hecho creando un nuevo método en la clase llamado `getNoHomeros()` (aunque un nombre más propio sería `getNotRepeated()` o algo así).

Por ejemplo:

```
class ClubDeNoHomeros {     
    List<String> integrantes = Arrays.asList("Homero", "Carl", "Lenny", "Homero", "Homero");
    
    long cantidadIntegrantes() {   
        return integrantes.size();     
    }

    public Set<String> getNoHomeros() {           
        Set<String> noHomeros = new HashSet<>(integrantes);
        return noHomeros;  
    }          
}
```

Prueba:

```
ClubDeNoHomeros mClub = new ClubDeNoHomeros();
System.out.println(mClub.getNoHomeros());
```

**Salida:**

```
[Homero, Carl, Lenny]
```

Comment: Tu solución no pasó las pruebas
Objetivos que no se cumplieron:
 ClubDeNoHomeros usa variables locales innecesarias; podés retornar directamente la expresión
 getNoHomeros usa variables locales innecesarias; podés retornar directamente la expresión
Resultados de las pruebas:
 el_club_de_no_homeros_tiene_tres_integrantes Ver detalles
expected:<3> but was:<5>
 el_club_de_no_homeros_no_tiene_en_cuenta_los_integrantes_repetidos Ver detalles
null
 el_club_de_no_homeros_tiene_cuatro_integrantes_si_agrego_alguno_que_no_existe_muchas_veces Ver detalles
null

Comment: @user279378 intenta modificarlo de este modo: `public Set<String> getNoHomeros() { return new HashSet<>(integrantes); }`

Comment: tira el mismo resultado, sigue sin funcionar

Comment: @user279378 el código en sí mismo es correcto. Los problemas que mencionas parecen ser propios de tu entorno de práctica, lo cual ya escapa a nuestro alcance.

Comment: class ClubDeNoHomeros {
  Set<String> integrantes = new HashSet (Arrays.asList("Homero", "Carl", "Lenny", "Homero", "Homero"));

  
  long cantidadIntegrantes() {
    return integrantes.size();
  }}

Comment: le di mil vueltas, y con ese codigo me lo tomo como correcto, no se muy bien el porque jaja

Comment: @user279378 como te decía en mi anterior comentario, no es que el código en sí sea erróneo, simplemente no se adaptaba a tu contexto de práctica. Quizá convendría que para futuras preguntas, cuando se trate de un ejercicio, lo indiques con claridad, y si tu contexto de práctica tiene algunas restricciones, que también las indiques. Saludos.

Comment: perfecto, gracias por la ayuda.